# Better way to find an icon for a running process?

Tags: windows, icons, locate

I am trying to borrow an icon that is found in Visual Studio. The "Quick Action" light bulb icon. Using a screen capture is not good enough since it has a lot of semi-transparent icons, so I resorted to resource hacker.

I did an entire search of the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0' directory, but I couldn't find the icon in question. Then while ensuring that the icon was being displayed on the screen, I did a search looking for the current running processes (starting with the devenv.exe) -- but I still cannot find this icon. I have spent about 2 hours on this already but I cannot for the life of me find this icon.

I wonder if it should be this hard. Is there some sort of tool that I can point and click on an application and it would tell me which processes/DLLs are in the background so I can narrow my search? In fact is there ANY tool out there that could help me narrow my search?

Comment: Ah, its not copyright infringement, you are just borrowing it.

Comment: Not at all. I am modifying the icon heavily so it is my derivative work of 'art'.

Answer (score 1):

[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) is able to tell you which process a window belongs to (crosshair button). Once you know the process you can look at its loaded modules in the lower pane.

PE modules can contain two types of resources. Extract classic win32 resources with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and .NET resources with a tool like [DotNetResourcesExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dot_net_resources_extract.html)...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did as you mentioned. I dragged the crosshair and it (as expected) pointed me to devenv.exe. I looked into the sub-processes, but none of them have any icons (I used IconsExtract to look for icons in the EXEs/DLLs). After a day looking for this pesky icon, I think it is time to call it quits :( -- I created a simpler icon from scratch.